# r plot different data.frames on the same graph

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a list of 4 data.frames which different names which look like:

`date x`

`01-03-2012 0.66`

`01-06-2014 0.44`

...

What I need: I need a plot with for colored sets of dots. Each set of dots should correspond to one data frame. Date ranges are different (one data.frame may start in 2011 and another - in 2012)

I tried to make this

`plot(x~date,toplot$a,xlab = "date", ylab = "value" , type= "o", col="red )`

`points(toplot$b$date, toplot$b$x,col="green")`
`points(toplot$c$date, toplot$c$x,col="black")`
`points(toplot$d$date, toplot$d$x,col="blue")`

But the first command draws small black lines instead of points, although `type= "o"` and doesn't change color to red
`toplot` is a list of data.frames, a,b,c,d - are data.frames.

If I add another data.frame data with `par(new=TRUE)` and another plot command, small black lines for both data.frames are drawn. The same situation with `plot(..., add=TRUE)`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First: for a point plot you use `type="p"` or nothing, because it plots points as default. Second: in the Code you showed here a `"`  is missing in `col="red"` but this should give an error or at least the command is not executed, because R waits for the closing `"`

Comment: I wrote `"p"` instead of `"o"` and checked all the ". It's the same: small  horizontal lines instead of dots for the first command. Not it is:

`plot(x~date,toplot$cleaness,xlab = "date", ylab = "value" , main = hotel, type= "p", col = "red" )`